# Can a NTFS drive with DST error be salvaged?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, backup, data-recovery, testdisk

I have a Windows laptop that suddenly won't boot. Running diagnostics shows that the secondary HD is failing with short DST error.

That's easy enough to fix by getting a replacement, but can the data be salvaged using Linux?

I booted into the laptop using a Kali distribution and ran `testdisk` and it seems able to still scan the drive bit by bit.
So the drive is not completely dead. I can create an image copy, but I didn't find a way to read the data.

What could I try to salvage the data before replacement? I'm looking for Linux commands that might help me salvage data.

Comment: `dd` is your friend. Why you'd need kali for this task is beyond me, though.

Comment: Because I happen to have it in USB. What else would I use and what ds commands? Thanks

Comment: Make an image copy with `dd` (or `ddrescue` if you get lots of read errors), recover what you need from the copy.  Or you can clone the failing drive to a new drive of the same size or larger ([clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) is a good USB-bootable live distro for this).   kali's pretty much useless for anything except as a honeypot to get clueless wannabe script-kiddies to waste their time on a broken distro - it's so cool, it was on TV.